# MQTT client for ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, mqtt, paho

I am developing an app for IOS and need MQTT client, I searched and there are similar questions asking which client to use for iOS, paho c client seems to be popular choice, but some people are suggesting that apple doesn't approve c clients for communication stuff. i have 2 questions.

1) which is most reliable/mature/complete MQTT client lib for iOS.

2) is it approved by apple and they will accept app that uses it.

I would prefer native objective-c libraries if they are available.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The '[MQTT Client Framework](https://github.com/ckrey/MQTT-Client-Framework)' is rock stable and is used e.g. in the iOS version of Owntracks. It has a lot of features compared to other libraries. The Owntracks app is available in the iOS App Store, so I guess Apple accepts this framework.

You can find a detailed blog post about the usage of the library written by the author here: http://www.hivemq.com/mqtt-client-library-encyclopedia-mqtt-client-framework/

Comment: is this framework work for background data fetching? in ios